# selecting an item in a listbox to assign it as a temp variable

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I currently have 2 listboxes (lstbox1 and lstbox2). Both listboxes have data in them which were inputted via StreamReaders, with ArrayLists to hold all the data from the file.

Currently, my lstbox1 comprises of: Genre, GenreDesc, AgeRange (These are just the variable names i have given them, the actual file looks like this):

- Action, DescriptionHere, 12+
- Horror, DescriptionHere, 18+
- Comedy, DescriptionHere, 12+

This is just a sample of the text file which was put into my lstbox1 via SR.

What I am trying to do is, when i select an item from lstbox1, it would filter out the Movies in lstbox2 that match the Genre i selected, and display that in the listbox.

My second textfile was inputted into lstBox2 and looks like this (movieTitle, movieGenre, movieDesc, movieRating:

- Transformers, Action, DescriptionHere, 77/100
- The Hangover, Comedy, DescriptionHere, 52/100
- The Dark Knight, Action, DescriptionHere, 85/100
- The Matrix, Action, DescriptionHere, 74/100

As both listboxes comprise of multiple variables, I want my lstbox1 to specify Genre, and ignore the other values that are in there, so that when i select a value from lstBox1 it will search specifics..

```
if (lstBox1.Genre == lstBox2.movieGenre)
{
    lstbox2.items.clear();
    //Add Genre Name as header (Based upon your selected item)
    //Add movieTitle + movieDesc + movieRating
}
```

& loop this around till all the movies have been searched.

I have made 2 classes (1 for Genres, 1 for Movies) & I am unsure of how to select the 'Genre' part out of lstBox1 to use as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have loaded the `lisBox1` with objects of type `Genre`.

```
lisBox1.Datasource = this.GetAllGenresFromTextFiles();
lisBox1.DisplayMember = "Genre";
```

Add an event to `SelectionChanged` of your `lstBox1` :

```
lstBox1.SelectionChanged += lstBox1_SelectionChanged;
```

And then in this event, filter the data for listbox2 :

```
void lstBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var movies = m_allMovies;
    var genre = lstBox1.SelectedItem as Genre;
    if(genre != null)
    {
        movies = movies.Where(m => m.Genre == genre.Genre).ToList();
    }
    lstbox2.Datasource = movies;
}
```

`m_allMovies` is a list of all the movies you have loaded from your textfiles.
You can also read your text file every time the user clicked a different genre, it will consume less memory but more CPU:

```
void lstBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var movies = this.GetAllMoviesFromTextFiles();
    var genre = lstBox1.SelectedItem as Genre;
    if(genre != null)
    {
        movies = movies.Where(m => m.Genre == genre.Genre).ToList();
    }
    lstbox2.Datasource = movies;
}
```

The keypoint here is not to filter row from the `Listbox`. You must think of it as your `Listbox` contains a subset of all your movies.
And each time you want to add or remove rows from a `Listbox`, in fact you are reloading it with appropriate datas.

Comment: With the first 2 lines of code (At the top of your answer), where would i place this (I'm new to C# so .Datasource & DisplayMember are new things to me). Also where you have "this.GetAllGenresFromTextFiles" (and the same for var movies = this.GetAllMoviesFromTextFiles) --> would i place the location of my text file within the brackets?

Comment: The answers to your question are beyond the context of this thread, and I advise you to go http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.